# HTML 5 Navigator Online - Redirect ,keeps making infinite tabs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, caching

Hello i am using html 5 app cache to cache some files for offline use.
I am also using HTML 5 navigator online, so when when there is no internet the website redirects the user to another page. 
The problem is that once i cached my files, turn off my internet, once i hit reload button or through address bar , it pops infinite tabs until it goes offline, and i only need 1 tab :)

Login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">           
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
  <title>Online Drawing for Electricians</title>

</head>              
<body>      
     <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container text-center">
<h1>Online Drawing for Electricians</h1>
     <div class="container">
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">(Online)Please login in</h2>
<label for="inputtext" class="sr-only">Username</label>
<input name="username" type="text" id="inputtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    if (navigator.onLine) {

} else {
  window.open("http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php");
}
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>              
</html>
```

Loginjs.php (alternative page while offline)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">           
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
  <title>Online Drawing for Electricians</title>
</head>              
<body>              

     <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container text-center">
<h1>Online Drawing for Electricians</h1>
     <div class="container">
         <h2 class="form-signin-heading">(Offline)Please login in</h2>
         <form class="form-signin" method="post">
<input type="text" id="username" class="form-control">
<input type="password" id="password" class="form-control">
<input type="button" button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"value="Log in" onClick="clicked()">
         </form>
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/login.js"</script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    if (navigator.onLine) {

} else {
  window.open("http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php");
}
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>              
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
if (navigator.onLine) {

} else {
  window.open("http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php");
}
```

to:

```
if (!navigator.onLine) {
  window.location ='http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php'; //edit, should be '=', not a func
}
```

---

and in the second page (offline page), remove the javascript:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {

} else {
  window.open("http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php");
}
```

No guarantees, but it should work.

**Edit:** In the second page (offline page), you're missing a `>`:

`<script src="/js/login.js"</script>`   Should be:

`<script src="/js/login.js"></script>`

---

**Edit (2):**

The reason for the original '*Spamming*' of pages was caused by the repeat of the following snippet:

```
if (navigator.onLine) {

} else {
  window.open("http://www.lifeofaris.se/loginjs.php");
}
```

In the second page (offline page). This is because when you are redirected to the offline page, the online page's JS has worked out that you are offline and opened a new page. Now you have this offline page opened, you still have the code to check if you are offline, and since you are it will open a *new* offline page.

Each of these new offline pages contains the same code that checks if you are offline, and since you are looking at the offline page, you are obviously offline, and so will keep on opening new pages, that is why I said to remove the snippet from the 'offline' page.

Comment: It worked ,thank you, but what was the problem? was the window.open the problem?

Comment: @ArisConstantinou I will edit my answer to explain what caused the problem, Check back in a few minutes and it should be there.

Comment: @ArisConstantinou There we go, Done.